# What AutoReviewComments have you come up with?

Tags: discussion

As many already know, there is a [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script call [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to automatically insert comment text for common situations.

The stock comments are less than stellar in my opinion. What comments have you come up with?

Comment: Maybe we should expand this list with some comments regarding to question closure. Ex: `This question was closed because it was a shopping question. Shopping questions are considered not constructive because they have a very limited lifespan.` Or something alike. Anyone who is up for it?

Answer (score 4):

My current automagic comments are here http://pastebin.com/XHBkSRiy

```
###[A]Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)
We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

###[A]Another user adding a 'Me too!'
This is an old question, if it's answers don't help you then please ask your own question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.

###[Q]Belongs on SU
Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

###[Q]Belongs on SO
Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it appears to relate programming. It may be on topic for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

###[Q]Belongs on AU
Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but please [search](http://askubuntu.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

###[Q]Belongs on U&L
Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) but please [search](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

###[Q]Belongs on SU | U&L
Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for. It may also be on topic for [u&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) but again, please [search](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

### Spammer
Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://$SITEURL$/faq#promotion).

###[Q]More information required
Now's a great time to edit your question and provide as much detail as possible. If you aren't sure what to add, see [How can I ask better questions on $SITENAME$?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632) and [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
###Using an Answer for anything else
[SF] **is not a forum**. Please do not post Answers unless they *actually answer 
the Question*. This should be posted as a Comment to the Answer it is replying 
to. See the [FAQ] for more details. Thank you and welcome to [SF]!

###Shopping Question
Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, 
lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-
shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.
```

Comment: Welcome to $site is automagically inserted if the user has only 1 rep.

Comment: Really... hadn't noticed that yet.

Comment: The SF FAQ now reflects the shopping part as well, with the addition of `[not about...] Product or service recommendations`

Answer (score 3):

(check the source for markup)

```
###Linux Network-troubleshooting
```

> Could you connect to the server via ssh and give us the output for the following commands: `iptables -L -v -n`, `chkconfig --list` and `netstat -an`? Make sure you do this with the appropriate rights (`sudo` or `su`).

```
###Solved? Mark it!
```

> It's nice to see your question was resolved/answered. Could you please mark it as such? If there is no appropriate answer below, make one yourself and accept it when you can.

```
###Asks for tutorial
```

> What have you tried so far? Did you get an error? Provide us with errors and/or logs.

```
###Low Accept Rate
```

> People are going to be wary of offering you answers as long as you have a low accept rate. That's because this community thrives on having good answers to good questions. If someone has given you a good answer in the past, but you did not mark it as such, the community is weakened. Now, if you truly did not get good answers to your previous questions, then edit your previous questions and say that you're still looking for a satisfactory answer.

```
###Other related problem
```

> Welcome to $SITENAME$! This is an old question. If it's answers don't help you directly then you should ask a new NEW question by clicking the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 2):

#### Totally Off-Topic

```
This question has been closed because it does not fit within the scope
of our site. Please familiarise yourself with our [FAQ] section "What can I
ask here", and more importantly, "What kind of questions should I *not* ask
here". There may be a more appropriate site on the [SE] network to help you.
```