# Why close questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Why do people close questions here when they are not fully answered? Why is it not a real question to ask why a server stops running after one day and to ask for the reason? Why is it not possible to post the solution for others while some "god-user" closes questions. I found the solution and thank you to the users who helped me with their hints.

https://serverfault.com/questions/450276/php-keeps-losing-connection-to-mysql-database

Please remove my account. Thanks

Comment: @HopelessN00b This would get closed without a second thought on mSO. I don't send questions to Certain Death if I can help it.

Comment: I find this question and the surrounding answers pretty informative. I recommend it be kept alive for future reference. I have thus upvoted it +1.

Comment: At the end it was a problem of the 3 party code from the wiki software we use. Every day after 24 hours when a special event occures a table reorganisation was started. In this code there was an LOCK TABLE which stopped the complete database. The last 4 years this was no problem. Within a few minutes now all 800 connections where full. The hint with pdo, mysqli and to trace the connections was it. My problem was i had to start the server very fast and i had no time to analyse the problem in case of stop. Also the problem was only once a day. Thank you again

Answer (score 12):

As one of the five users that voted to close your question, I'll ask you to indulge me for a second.

Imagine you're me and I'm you. You know nothing of the environment in question. All that you know is what I've told you: it crashes a lot and it's MySQL. What details have I given you to help solve this mystery? A copy of `my.conf`.

How are you ever going to figure out the problem with these details?

The answer is that you can't, which makes it `Not a Real Question`, at least in my opinion. I realize that there is an edit button and that you can update your information if necessary, but if I see a question that has so terribly few details and the user doesn't seem to have done any triage themselves, then I vote to close it. No good details + minimal effort to solve the issue yourself = closed question.

Comment: [Context! The difference between roadkill, and a meal!](http://www.bsd-box.net/~mikeg/context)

Comment: Have you really read before you vote? Did't you see the whole my.conf? Whats wrong with you guys. If you don't like to give support what are you doing here?

Comment: I read your whole my.conf. Did you read my whole answer?

Answer (score 9):

I'm sorry, but your question as asked was woefully incomplete. There is no ***useful*** information provided which would reasonably enable us to troubleshoot your problem and help you arrive at a solution.
Further, when asked to provide some information to assist us with troubleshooting you simply dumped your entire configuration file on us and left us to sort through it.  This is not something that endears you to the site regulars: We expect that you will do at least *some* of the basic troubleshooting work -- especially "find the value of `x`", and will scan your logs (all of them, if you're not sure which one to look at) for "unusual" or "interesting" events which you can then report to us.

Remember that we do not know your environment -- we expect that you, as a *professional system/network administrator* (per our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq)), will [assemble a good question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) (strongly recommended reading), and do most of the legwork required to get us the information we need.
Questions that do not include adequate information are "not a real question" -- perhaps not the best name, but certainly the correct reason:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. ***This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*** For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

<sup>Emphasis Added</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The question in question here was closed after five users with close-voting rights (3000 rep) thought it was worthy of a close. A god-user (one of us with diamonds) didn't close the question.

The question was closed as Not A Real Question. I can't speak for the five close-voters, but at a guess the question got closed for two reasons:

1. **Insufficient evidence of troubleshooting before arriving at StackOverflow**, and thus little for us to work on beyond the most generic "it doesn't work, why" workflow. Questions like these require a fair amount of back-and-forth with the asker to get what we're looking for, and that didn't happen before it got closed.
2. **A migration from StackOverflow.** There is a bit of a prejudice around surrounding such questions, since they have a strong tendency to be either crap or out of scope.

Comment: I like your second reason. ...crap... Got to laugh at that one. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry guys i got the help i needed. The two persons who could understand my question, gave me the hints i needed to find the solution. Had i knew before what i have to give you for imformation i would not be asked for help. I can read log files by myself. If you are able to read, i also asked which info i should give to help. So guys be happy with 3000 and more reputations. This was a fail. But my production problem is solved and so i'm happy.