# What's wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, moderation, doomed

Can anyone please kindly tell me what's wrong is my question?

https://serverfault.com/questions/473739/

Why it's not a real question?

Comment: See the FAQ: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.`  Please provide more background information about how you ran across this very interesting oddity in Windows name resolution, and how it applies to a problem you're having.

Comment: @ShaneMadden It's just a cmd typo for me, and I don't want to solve anything, just want to know why it works on Windows.

Comment: That's really more of a trivia question than anything - unless it applies to a problem you're having, then it's not really appropriate for Server Fault.  In any case, then answer seems to be "because Microsoft wrote it that way".  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ShaneMadden Thanks a lot, you are my hero. That's the exact MSDN page I want to find myself but failed.

Answer (score 7):

At least five high-reputation community members have absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

For me, I've never heard of `..localmachine` and I can't tell whether it's something you typed in or an example meant to stand for something else. You also didn't provide an example of the commands you ran and the output you are seeing.

I would suggest explaining exactly what you are doing, what led you to this `..localmachine` thing, what it *is*, and some command output.

For more on how you can improve questions, see [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)

Comment: dear sir, trying "ping ..localmachine" only takes two seconds, I am on  a non-English Windows machine so I the output I provide is something like this https://gist.github.com/4679003 do you find it helpful?

Comment: can you please kindly show me how to properly ask this question instead?

Comment: @est We can't tell you how to ask your question, because (as stated above) we've never heard of what you're talking about. The best advice I can give you is to read [this topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608) and try re-asking your question with adequate detail.

Comment: @voretaq7 Is it fair to close a question just because mods never heard of it? Can't you guys kindly suggest an edit? I re-asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14616654/41948) with adequate detail, but Mr Michael Hampton is asking me to stop, and Mr ThiefMaster decided to close it even the answer is already there. So what am I doing wrong in my second attempt?

Comment: @est I _did_ suggest an edit, but you decided not to take my advice.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry that was my fault. It was too late as I am not at your timezone, by the time I tried to improve the first question it was already closed. So I went ask the second question on Stackoverflow  instead.

Comment: @est What does that have to do with anything? You can improve your question at any time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hmm, you have never experienced that frustration when your topic is closed (Which means NO ANSWERS allowed), and kind people can only answer your question correctly on a meta site. It's like you were put into prison for seeking knowledge but instead acquired that knowledge in a courtroom.

Comment: @est Your question was closed. That means you can edit it so that it can be reopened.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I edited the question [at my best effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616654/#comment20413100_14616654). still not sure how to meet the question standards. Anyway it's obscure open question as on Windows it can happen at any level, (hardcode in commands? API? or winsock?). SO/SF hate these as it's more like open research rather than solving practical problems. it's a personal curiosity inquiry, not a real coding/server problem worthy to solve. For such a stupid question, most ppl tend to take granted to close it as they never heard of it nor want to peek into it. /rant

Answer (score 4):

I can think of a few things... first -- you didn't actually *ask a question*.

Comment: Hi @tylerl I asked the complete question in the headline, sorry about the poor content, I updated it. Can you please suggest me edit content not closing the question next time?

Comment: The second time you asked the question, you did a much better job. Questions that just say "why does(n't) this work" expect the answerer to do all the work and figure out the context of what you're talking about, the expected behavior, any unusual circumstances, etc. The more clear you are, the more likely people will be able to answer you.