# Why was this question closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

If someone can explain to me why the [following](https://serverfault.com/questions/518203/windows-7-home-folder-is-missing-from-gui) was closed as 'off-topic', I would appreciate it. I will use the feedback to improve the question or just remove it.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you're an end user rather than the administrator of the systems.

Comment: From your comment, would I be correct in inferring that whoever asks a question on serverfault has to be an admin?

Comment: Basically.  This is in the first sentence of the FAQ: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok. I see that. I also see, on the home page, where it reads 'Anyone can ask a question'. In any event, my question was not well presented so that is that. I will improve it and come back with more information.

Comment: Please don't. You're not an admin of the system you're asking about.

Comment: Actually, I am. I just don't know enough, yet, on how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server Fault is dedicated to serving a particular market: *Professional system and network administrators*  (https://serverfault.com/about ; https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

From you question it's pretty evident that you're not the system administrator responsible for this environment.  Wanting to know something for your own education is an admirable thing, but it does not make it an on-topic question for this site.

---

In this case even if you are the system administrator for the environment involved, your question doesn't meet our quality standards -- There is no evidence of research or troubleshooting, a nearly infinite set of possible causes, and so the question simply cannot be answered as asked.

[We have a Q&A here on meta that discusses some things that go into making a good, answerable question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault), but the basic premise is that you need to do some (fairly extensive) digging on your own, and at least summarize that work so we're not going over the same ground.

Comment: Thank you. I will come back with more information. I assume I would need to create a new question.

Comment: @KernelPanic If the question is substantially the same (just made "better") simply Edit the existing question then Flag it for reopening.

Comment: I was not aware that was an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I won't speak for any of the five people who voted to hold the question, but...

My primary problem with this is that, by your own admission, it's a purely hypothetical question. You aren't actually trying to solve a real problem. This means that, while it may be possible to "answer" the question, it's entirely impossible for a "correct" answer to be given.

This is the reason that we only allow [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I don't see where I indicate it is a hypothetical situation. I am truly trying to solve that problem.