# Where can i get an idea other than here?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, questions

https://serverfault.com/questions/533609/why-isnt-qmail-been-downloading-from-a-version-control-system

Above question of me is down voted and i think it is going to be closed

Answer (score 12):

Assessing the continued development probabilities of an open source project is very much a soft skill and not all professional systems administrators have it. Unfortunately for you, this kind of assessment doesn't have any hard and fast rules, so the answers are going to be entirely subjective. This makes the question too broad.

Comment: Yup: This is an assessment *you* have to make @tuxi - we can't do it for you. For my part, in environments I manage, I can assess the development possibilities of qmail very easily: *develop* a plan to get rid of it ***ASAP***.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it has been downvoted and will most likely be closed. This is because your question is unclear and therefore unanswerable.

You should try reading [How to ask a better question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) and consider revising your question.