# Why are all my FreeNX questions recieved so poorly

Tags: discussion

I read through a few of these meta questions about 'bad questions' I'm getting a sense peeps are fed up with bad questions get'n dumped on ya'll from StackOverflow--my guess. And reading the [What Topics I Can Post](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), I believe my post fits the two criteria:

> If your question is about… *Server ... operating systems... and software*.
>
> and it is not about… Anything in a *home* or development environment

We'll I guess you got me on the **last one**. While this is a **Server/RAID running CentOS6 (e.g. EL)**, it is *technically* located in a home.

Goodness knows I've put *some* effort into writing my posts.

[Why would sshd daemon fail a connection that manually started /usr/sbin/sshd permits?](https://serverfault.com/questions/544181/why-would-sshd-daemon-fail-a-connection-that-manually-started-usr-sbin-sshd-per)

[How do I configure FreeNX APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PRELOAD to the correct directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/544746/how-do-i-configure-freenx-application-library-preload-to-the-correct-directory)

- there are only 18 questions here with the tag freenx,
- none of them ask the same question
- as I stated in the post, it may be an easy/lame question, but its not my fault the error message is included in **tons** of people's
  posts which have nothing to do with this problem.
- Enterprise Linux has been using FreeNX 0.7 since 2009 or earlier. Is it so inconceivable I may have found some new or infrequently mentioned problem? Geez
- SELinux

And! Its just damn confusing, because I get the impression many people are unhappy with FreeNX development.

Why are all my FreeNX questions get'n shat on? It sure as s#it hasn't stopped me from trying to get NX working. Or asking questions...

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: FreeNX is a dead project which was last updated 5 years ago and never really usable to begin with. Using such a piece of software violates our "prime directive": **Professional** system administration.

Comment: What is the replacement? Right...I could tell you but I'd have to kill you...

Comment: "it is technically located in a home." <-- It's not described in detail in the help center but we differentiate between "home" the location and "home" the environment. The former is just a location and unimportant, the latter encompasses conduct, expectation, standards, and generally professionalism (or the lack thereof in "home environments".

Comment: I've already gotten the memo about binaries and non-repo installs at Cent. The project may not be commercial, but it is professional.

Comment: @xtian: NoMachine NX. It's the original and it works. It's not cheap  though, but there was a limited version usable for one user that used to be free, but I am not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: So the two questions you linked to, didn't have any comments or downvotes when I first looked at them, so what is your problem?  Why do you think your questions are being treated badly?

Comment: I can't say with certainty, as I haven't downvoted them. But I can guess that your first question reads like a diary entry more than a "question". The second uses "cuz" and that's reason enough for me to stop reading and downvote a question.

Comment: Chris S. meet Xtian (Christian) S, What up Cuz! ...

Comment: Zoredache, I don't know if you can see history but both questions had -2 when I first checked. I didn't say I was being treated badly, I'm saying _my questions_ were get'n s#at on. Right now, everyone seems to me just fine.

Comment: Z, and after taking a peek at your rep., I'd guess there is very little you can't oversight here on servf

Comment: And I guess Michael wants a _question_. Your wish is my command...

Comment: `What is the replacement?` - the xfreerdp server looks pretty promising.  It permits RDP access to a X11 instance.  Still has some bugs here and there, but freerdp seems to be the most actively developed GUI remote access tool these days.

Comment: @xtian Re: "What is the replacement for FreeNX / NX Technologies?" - that sounds like an excellent question for the main site. There are a lot of options (a few have been mentioned here). If you give us a summary of what you're trying to do and tell us you're trying to replace FreeNX we might be able to point you at alternatives.

Comment: @Zoredache, I took a quick look and freerdp is available in CentOS EPEL repo: freerdp-1.0.2-1.el6.i686.rpm and, its also available for Arch. The question I _want_ to know about is, given the interoperability issue, which clients work with which servers. Wikipedia has a nice round up of some alternatives, but it doesn't tell mention if any one solution works with another--or that peeps are steamed bout the Freenx fiasco.

Comment: There's a new NX version, which while closed source, kicks ass from my initial experiments. Just worked through my initial windows experiment, ubuntu is next. seriously worth checking out

Comment: Yes. v4. And they do allow 2 free client connections...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any serious problems with your questions, other than the fact that some are fairly "novice" questions (which isn't a bad thing, it's just a thing - Everyone starts somewhere).

You only seem to have one that has attracted (as of my writing this) a single downvote, and your reputation changes have been largely positive -- that's a pretty good track record.

I do have a few general suggestions though:

---

**First, try not to take downvotes so personally.**
Seriously man, you'll give yourself an ulcer. The standard boilerplate here is:

> Users are free to upvote or downvote questions for whatever reasons they want - there are some guidelines when you hover over the arrows, but much like when you go to the polls on election day voting on Stack Exchange is an entirely individual choice.  Mods and SE staff pretty much don't get involved.

---

**Second, try to write your questions in a way that conforms to Standard Written English.**
There is no hard and fast rule on this (aside from ["It has to be *in English*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)), and we're a lot more relaxed about it on Meta, but slang, venting, ranting, etc. are all looked upon as a Bad Thing. [Questions should be distilled down to to "This is my problem, this is what I've tried to solve it, and this is what didn't work"](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault).

---

**Finally, don't rant.**
At least one of your questions that I looked at ([the one with the downvote, incidentally](https://serverfault.com/questions/544746/how-do-i-configure-freenx-application-library-preload-to-the-correct-directory)) is a little ranty, and things that look like rants tend to get reflex-downvoted.

In a related vein, it's generally considered bad form to tell the people reading your question what you want the answer to be (stuff like `And please don't say compile from source, cuz CentOS hates that answer...`) -- Trust me when I say the people answering questions here know what the vendors prefer, and if we tell you to do something a certain way there's probably a good reason for it (you can always ask us why we recommend something if you think we're crazy).

Comment: IF I think you're all crazy! ehehe

Comment: Well, crazier than typical for a bunch of sysadmins who are all at work and therefore can't have our whisky.

Comment: "Juice of the Barley for me!"