# Mis-closed question: I am a sys admin, this topic is "on topic", and I did perform research

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I was directed to post my request for re-opening of a question from Comms Room here.

The following question was closed as off-topic, but it is not off-topic as defined.

> "Questions must be relevant to professional system administration. Server Fault is dedicated to professional system and network administrators. End user and enthusiast questions are off-topic (contact your system administrator or hire a professional to help you out). Please see the Help Center for more information." – SvW, Falcon Momot, mdpc, Ward, Nathan C

[Windows 7 WMI ODBC driver installation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/585645/windows-7-wmi-odbc-driver-installation)

I believe the following two actions should have taken place:

1. The topic should not have been closed at all, particularly not under the "off topic" rule.
2. The topic *could* have been migrated to Stack Overflow, but it is not a programming question, so that is invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that your question is not off-topic. But, it also doesn't show any details or research on your part. It has several lines of exposition, followed by a single short question: "How do I do XYZ". Please have a read through [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

On a side note, I know the answer to your question...

Comment: I'm going to guess that the original close-voters considered trying to install a discontinued product on an OS for which it wasn't designed as `not being relevant to professional system administration` which seems reasonable though.

Comment: That's a condescending personal attack, and I'm surprised that you received up votes for it.  Maybe that indicates something that needs further investigation.

Comment: @mbrownnyc I don't think "condescending personal attack" means what you think it means. He spoke out against **what you were doing**, which was indeed stupid, not about who you are personally.

Comment: I was trying to ride the righteous train, but I just can't mess with you meta guys.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @mbrownnyc - Well you're not doing yourself any favors here.

Comment: @EEAA That's the second guy in a week who lashed out about us attacking their character when we weren't... Maybe it's a new "thing"?

Comment: @ChrisS God help us if it is.

Comment: @ChrisS It's a thing, but it's not exactly new...

Comment: @ChrisS: Definitely a thing now :(