# Are 'best-practice' questions on-topic?

Tags: support, off-topic, allowed-topics

I have a small issue regarding involving 'best practice' on whether an SQL server should be run on a VPS or dedicated server.

I'm active on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and this type of question would be closed as `Primarily Opinion Based`; does the same close reason apply in this case?

Are such 'best-practice' questions off-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably have to see the actual question to offer an opinion on its suitability. But in general, system administration best practices are (or should be) well known, not usually disputed, and thus not really qualified to be closed as opinion-based. A question may be closed for other reasons, though, such as being too broad.

In regard to the information you did give us, I suggest you read [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for databases?](https://serverfault.com/q/350458/126632) before asking, as many questions along these lines would be closed as a duplicate of this question.

If you still feel the need to ask the question, provide as much detail as possible about the proposed architecture, the business case, and [anything else that may be relevant](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632).

Comment: I'd err on the side of posting it anyway.