# Dealing With Questionable Actions Taken By Moderators

Tags: discussion

[MS Terminal Server Blocking Website Access](https://serverfault.com/questions/663771/ms-terminal-server-blocking-website-access#)

A few helpful people came to give it a shot.  They specified what they needed clarified and I obliged.

Then I had two moderators come around, that seemed mildly rude and pretty non-constructive.  I politely asked for clarification as to what I was missing, and what they wanted, and was met with resistance.

The question was locked as off-topic when it clearly pertained to servers and networking, and when there were others that understood what was occurring and wanted to answer.

Turns out the first answer was correct, and luckily I was able to mark it as such even after the post was closed.

I believe this helps show I provided enough circumstance to allow someone to answer the question.

How do we prevent such events from occurring?

Comment: 1) I'm not a moderator (why does everyone assume that?) 2) my comments may have come off snarky but that was because I felt like you weren't putting much effort into solving your own issue.  I explained that you could simply change a client's hosts file to test resolution.  Then you said "well of course that works but it's a hack", to which I replied "you should've said that it works doing that in your OP.  Then it's obviously a DNS resolution issue and you should post a debugged output of an nslookup if you want further help" which you never did.  I'm glad you got it resolved still.

Comment: @TheCleaner I did not realize whether or not the domain resolved being in the hosts file was helpful in narrowing the decision tree, if I did I would have posted it.  I don't think the comments were so much snarky as mixed constructive...  I appreciate the help, but I do wish people would understand that others may not have thought of everything and all they need is a simple comment asking them to clarify.  Not a comment challenging the whole post when the OP is willing to improve it.  I assumed you were a mod because it was closed with 2 votes before reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question appears answerable to me as it stands now, so I've reopened it. I've also cleaned up the comments, as they aren't relevant to the question as it now stands.

With regard to rude behavior, if you believe a user has been rude, then flag the post or comment and we'll look at it. If it's an actual *moderator* (who all have diamonds next to their names) who you believe has been rude, then contact Stack Exchange using the contact us form linked at the bottom of every page.

Finally, one thing I would advise you to do in the future is to provide "everything I can think of" in your question initially, so that people do not have to ask you repeatedly to provide the information and waste time going down the same dead ends. [Good questions include as much detail as is necessary](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632). Also remember that if someone *is* asking you in comments for information or to test something, it's because they believe that will be helpful in isolating the problem, not necessarily because they think it will be the final solution.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent moderation and information.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to avoid having questions closed is to start out with a good, answerable question with an easily defined scope.  As it now stands, your question is fine, but it's been edited 3 times, and there have been 23 comments on the question and answer, many of which gave the impression that you didn't possess a sufficient degree of experience or level of understanding for us to assist.  Things like misinterpreting a diagnostic/troubleshooting step as a suggested solution, for example.  Add to that the fact that what ultimately ended up being the correct answer had to be edited into the answer as a response to one of your question edits, and you have what's actually a rather poor Q&A that was eventually salvaged into something useful, rather than a question that was good and topical to begin with.

Not asking a good question with sufficient information leads to situations where multiple answers are posted, based on incomplete information, the question is edited multiple times invalidating the existing answers, and a lot of time and effort is spent on a Q&A thread that's completely useless to any future visitors because it's so convoluted and twisted around by the time it's successfully answered, or more often, abandoned for being not worth the trouble.

It's also helpful to understand the standards of the community in which you're posting, as well as the way the site you're using works, which you very clearly don't.  You'd tried to direct a question to a couple users by editing a question to them into your closed question, you're unfamiliar with the topicality rules of the site, don't appear to have read anything about the community (either how to ask a good question, or whom this community is composed of), and despite being a member on Stack Overflow for over 4 years, incorrectly identified a regular user as a moderator, didn't know the process for reopening a closed question and ostensibly were unaware of what to do when disagreeing with an actual moderator.

So there you have it - [reading up on how to ask a better question](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) and familiarizing yourself with the community are your best ways to "`prevent such events from occurring`".

Comment: I disagree in many ways, but do not have the space to fully express my thoughts.  I have seen great questions go through multiple edits.  People think they posted it right the first time and then realize they made an assumption that should be clarified with the feedback.  I don't know if you were having a bad day, or if you are the type that always gets the first post right and can't stand to see others not follow your standard, but its really nasty and counterproductive to act as you did.  No hard feelings dude, hope you have a much better weekend!

Comment: @BAR It's as much about the consequences of a poor question as the poor question itself. A poor question with no answers will get deleted by the system, and no big deal. A poor question which gets a bunch of answers and radically changes while it's being answered does not get automatically get cleaned up, and creates a mess that's a major pain in the ass to deal with/cultivate into something useful.  That's why your question was closed - so that it did not devolve any further, while giving you a chance to refine into a detailed, concise and useful question that could be reasonably answered.

Comment: I'm inclined to say the proper course of action would be cleaning up the comments and answers... However this is can be very tricky / cause the question to devolve.

Comment: @Reaces I wish I had some say over the cleanup.  As soon as I saw HopelessN00b and TheCleaners comments I knew this was about to devolve rapidly.  There should be an IGNORE button!

Comment: @bar what do you mean with devolve rapidly? They both gave reasonable responses...

Comment: @Reaces Their comments were removed by a moderator.

Comment: HopelessN00b **is** a moderator.  If you're going to use mod removal as evidence of the comment being poor, you must also use the original mod involvement as evidence of the comment being excellent.  Though I cannot read the comments now, the discussion above suggests that the question required a **lot** of work to make it fit-for-purpose; I don't think you should read any more into the removal of the comments than "*now the community has helped the author salvage this question, mods have come along and tidied that process up*", which often happens around these parts.

Comment: @MadHatter Everything in context.  The comments from hopelessn00b were mixed with attacks.  The first comment he made on this post was a direct attack.  This is what moderators here are supposed to be like? /sarc

Comment: @BAR The only comment I posted on your original question was: "`If all you know how to use is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.` Sadly, your problem is not a nail, and we're not a group of professional carpenters."  And it was an auto-posted comment by the question closure system... which is really something that someone who's been a member on SO for over 4 years ought to know.  Which brings me to the other comment I made at you, on this question, pointing that out. If you see either of those comments as attacks, perhaps this community is not for you.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Why do you expect me to know that is auto-posted?  And what exactly is my hammer?  I clearly tried different things, such as nslookup, DNS admin, and ipconfig commands.  And how about your comment here?  That was definitely an attack, and it was removed because of it.

Comment: @BAR Jesus man, knock it off already. I don't have the patience to deal with your brand of... whatever you want to call this.  My comment here was `For someone who's been on Stack Overflow for over 4 years, you seem to have a bewilderingly poor understanding of the way Stack Exchange sites work.` It was not an attack, and its removal is in no way a validation of your flag or an indication that it was an attack. Now kindly stop irritating me with message notifications and overly sensitive claims about what constitutes an attack (to put it generously). Ask a new meta question if you must.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Its my brand of straight shooting.  You feel justified and I feel your wrong.  We clearly disagree.  That is fine.

Comment: @BAR I'm sorry, but - assuming you mean HN's comment above with 8 upvotes - I'd stand by everything he said in that comment, and have upvoted it myself.  It contains nothing *ad hominem* whatsoever, only some trenchant criticism of a class of questions that well-deserve it.  If you regard that as a "*direct attack*", you're way too thin-skinned for SF, and need to learn to distinguish between criticism of *what you've done* as opposed to criticism of *who you are*.  The former is entirely legitimate, and I've seen none of the latter.

Comment: @MadHatter I don't take it personally.  I do find it unbecoming of a moderator to be aggressive or even mildly rude while not helping the poster.

Comment: And as we keep trying to tell you, nothing we've seen here constitutes aggression.

Comment: @MadHatter Whatever it is, it is definitely not the polite thing to do, as the post linked by HN himself states a user should be.

Comment: @BAR Alright, I'm done asking.  If I get irritated by another message notification from you, like when you post a comment on my question, you're getting suspended.