# Why lock a question because a poorly worded locked duplicate with no answers exist?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I have a question here https://serverfault.com/questions/670436/how-do-i-use-tls-https-using-dane-dnssec IMO it's incorrectly marked as a duplicate. One question explains the problem and the expected results. The other was poorly worded and confused readers into locking it because they didn't understand it. Why are we locking both so no answers are possible? If you read both you'll see they are different questions trying to solve the same question and not a phrasing or a duplicate.

Comment: `they are different questions trying to solve the same question` I don't understand this. Is it like a light and dark way of resolving a quest? What's going on here!

Comment: @Reaces: I'll give an example. Lets say you have a '%' you want to display to the user in your console app. You can ask "How do I replace/print the percentage on the first line of my console window without messing up the lines below". That might sound like nonsense. Another way is to ask "How do I change the title of my console app" which has a more simple solution and solves your problem on how to display the percentage to the user. My question today was about how to make self signed certs work and the question yesterday was on signing cert with DNS keys (which may not be the correct way)

Comment: The problem is that neither of your questions is clear enough to ascertain what you're actually trying to achieve. Please, rather than responding to this comment, spend the time clarifying your questions.

Comment: @Iain: My first question there was one person who knew exactly what I was asking. I don't know what the confusion is to anyone who has an idea about the subject. But that doesn't answer this question about why are we locking on topic questions because there is a poorly written off topic question that looks similar. I don't think there would be a problem if we weren't locking questions without thinking

Comment: Since it's such a big deal to you, I have changed the close reason on that question.  It is now closed for being unclear what you're asking.  My advice about fixing your questions so other people can understand what you're asking about still stands.  This probably would be a better use of your time than, for example, antagonizing the moderators by flagging their comments as rude or offensive.

Answer (score 6):

Because you keep asking it.

If it's poorly worded, and doesn't have an answer you like, you have no one to blame but yourself for that.  Fix your old question and get it reopened; don't ask the same thing in a new question.

[You could probably benefit from reading the thread here on how to ask better questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258), as well as using the search function before asking a question.  This is far from the first time you've asked a question that was closed as a duplicate, or could have been answered by searching the site first.

Comment: I'm not convinced they are the same question and I clearly searched before asking and included a result from my search

Comment: @acidzombie24 Well, as I said, improve one or both of your questions so it's more clear what you're asking.  This might require some independent learning on your part... you seem to be fundamentally confused about some of the concepts you're asking about.