# What is the proper procedure when an old answer no longer works?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

The following scenario;

- You have the same problem as a previous asker, or a highly similar one.
- The previous answer has a working, accepted solution... 8 years ago.
- Things have changed (software updates breaking configuration, for example), and the solution is now different.
- You don't know the new solution yourself.

Attempting to ask the same question will in all likelyhood get quickly closed as a duplicate.

Trying to comment on the answer relies on the user that first answered still being active on the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally the same applies as with any other problem, you [ask a good question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that includes:

- What are you trying to do?
- What have you tried in order to make it happen?
- What results did you expect?
- What actually happened?

Where in step 2 you add something along the lines :

> I found `[link to this old Q&A]` that describes a similar problem  but that solution there is not applicable (anymore) because of `[reasons]`.

That generally prevents people from closing your question as a duplicate and shows that you're a professional that has done some research and/or tried a solution before asking the internet for help.

Adding the link to the old Q&A in your own question has the added benefit that your question will (usually) also appear reciprocally  in the "Linked" column of that old Q&A , directing people that found the old Q&A to your newer question. A good title for your own new question helps in that regard.

An example of this in practice is [this Q&A about the reliability of SSD drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/14189/reliability-of-ssd-drives) (from 2009) where the top Linked Q&A is [Are SSD drives as reliable as mechanical drives (2013)?](https://serverfault.com/q/507521/37681)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what's explained [HBrujin's excellent answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9863/435764), it's worth mentioning bounties.

Bounties allows you to give an explanation for why you're setting the bounty - and up to date answers is a legit reason for bountying a question.

Answer (score 2):

A question should not be closed merely because someone else has asked it.

Questions should be closed when an **answer** on another question provides a working solution to your question. (This also includes posted questions different from your question that have an answer which answers your question.)