# Why is the question about Nginx, MySQL and Wordpress is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bug

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Wordpress via 3 PHP versions](https://serverfault.com/questions/1139968/wordpress-via-3-php-versions)

Is here a place I'm able to ask questions about servers' software?
I thought the questions about installing Wordpress and needed Nginx, MySQL and PHP for it work is

> **managing the** hardware or **software of servers**, workstations, storage or networks

Isn't it?

Do Serverfault based more on questions about machine hardware and common software?

> Like home Minecraft server.

Example: If I want to get answer to my question I need to go to Stackexchange?

Comment: EOL software and the question is a test question.

Comment: You missed that [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.

Comment: Hand-holding, teaching the basics,  home work and home labs are definitely not on-topic. SuperUser might be more fitting for the knowledge level displayed in  such questions, or the generic Unix / Linux Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @HBruijn hm.. I cannot say I fully undestood the level difference between these resources; but thank you for help about other places where the question would be more appropriate