# "normal" close vote share

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close, reviewing

For a few days I have been having access to the close vote queue now and I am a bit shocked. My experience is limited to "Unix & Linux" where

1. IIRC the maximum number of items in the queue was two
2. I close nearly everything

When I looked at the close vote queue here it had ten items. Of course, SF has more questions than Unix but also a lot more users with enough rep to vote (and more moderators). But what's more important: It's maybe half of the questions where I admit to close them.

Meanwhile I am wondering whether I am the "softest" voter here or whether the difference to Unix is that some people here flag "everything they see".

One could discuss every single decision but now I am interested in a general impression: Do many people vote for "leave open" (i.e. is the problem the flagging and not my assessment)?

It might be interesting so see the overall "close" / "leave open" shares (and their distribution ;-) )

Comment: You could always look at the review history http://serverfault.com/review/close/history

Comment: So tempted to hit "Not constructive"... :)

Comment: @Iain But that shows the results for me only or do I miss something?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am sure you have noticed that the meta FAQ (i.e. on-topic definition) differs from the main site's FAQ...

Comment: @HaukeLaging: I see everyone's results.

Comment: @Iain: I think that's a 10k privilege. Hauke, fwiw, the proportion of 3k+ users to all users is about the same for U&L as for SF. And "Leave Open" reviews are roughly 1 in 5 on U&L based on a count of the last ~500 review actions. (Stack Overflow has over 50k questions in the close queue.)

Comment: @Mat: yes I forget agout that sort of stuff. Hauke from the last 100 voting actions 33/100 were leave open.

Answer (score 2):

I've done the most close vote reviewing, and I vote to close *a lot.*

As per some of the [pre-election discussion,](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5463/can-we-do-anything-to-change-the-dynamic-of-the-site) I think it would be useful to more precisely define (maybe with examples) what each of the close vote reasons means for "us" on SF...

...but in the meantime, I generally err on the side of voting to close.  It takes 5 to close, and although there's sometimes a bit of pile-on close-voting, it's rare for a good question to get closed, and of those, many get re-opened after an edit or clarification in Chat or meta.

(No, I don't leave comments: Although constructive comments might be useful (to go with the examples of bad questions), in most cases the close reason or downvote keytip are enough.)

I'm not exactly sure what the question was or if this is an answer, but I think voting (up/down/close) is the main tool for getting rid of crap, so I do it a lot and I never worry about whether I'm doing it "right."

Looking quickly at my reviewing, I get 57 leave open in the last 500 reviews, the rest were Close Votes.

Further to TheCleaner's post, if you want to check the review status of question you've reviewed:

1. click activity
2. then reviews
3. then click any of the "Close" or "Leave Opens" to see who voted which way
   [image: circles and arrows]

Comment: It looks like you probably Leave Open more often than I do. I only did 19 of those in my last 500.

Comment: I had a couple pages of reviews where I only had a couple Leave Opens and I thought maybe I was too harsh...

Answer (score 2):

After you vote on a question hit the back button in your browser if you want to see what others have done on that question up to that point:

[image]

I know for me, I use that every now and then, especially when I choose "Leave Open" or am asking myself "who the heck voted this as Off-Topic?"