# Migrate to Raspberry Pi option?

Tags: feature-request

There are quite a number of Raspberry Pi questions here at SF, and nearly all are from new SE profiles.

I suspect the users find SF through Google and so post here without realizing there is an SE site for Raspberry Pi.

How about adding the Rasberry Pi SE site as a migrate option? Seems like it would also be doing them the favor of finding a great Raspberry Pi community.

Comment: The trouble is that RPi.se don't want technical Unix questions, see point 5 in their off topic list [here][1] . They really should be migrated to unix.se. See also [this][2] and it's references.


  [1]: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
  [2]: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/raspberry-pis-and-server-fault

Comment: I would note too that often adding enterprise software on a PI can potentially make the subjet ontopic there, thus I always double check those question before a casting a move.

Comment: @yagmoth555: It's wide consensus here that RPi isn't a valid server platform and thus, all questions regarding this are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). See https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault. I would close with the "off topic because no reasonable business management practice" close reason.

Comment: @Sven I used to agree with you, as I was even against the use of small box (RPI included) to create soho homemade router, like for use with ddwrt or pfsense, but strangely the community let those question open, its another topic on the other side, but if the rpi is accepted for one enterprise use, for me its all or nothing.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Should it really be all or nothing? You can use an Android phone as a mail server, but I don't think configuring mail servers on Android is acceptable here at SF. However, configuring Android to work on your corporate network is on-topic, so each system I think can be more nuanced in policy based on application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not possible without first removing one of the other migrate options. There is a hard limit for the number of sites we can have in the migration list and the SE staff has always refused to add more.

I don't think removing one of the existing targets in favor of RPi would be a good idea as the other targets are much more important.

You can always leave a comment hinting about the existence of the other site and if you are sure it's a really good question flag for mod attention so that we can migrate it manually.