# Why would this question be off topic

Tags: discussion

[Linux how to bridge network through router](https://serverfault.com/questions/912595/linux-how-to-bridge-network-through-router)

The question has been marked as off topic and sent me back to the superuser stackexchange site. The fact being the device I'm debugging is a kiosk application and I'm having problem reproducing the client environment. I'm not asking about the context of the question because it's irrelevant to the question. It doesn't really matter if the RaspberryPI is a home device or being used as a kiosk. It's still just a RaspberryPI device.

And the question being technically just about network routing.

Would that make it less off topic if the context of the question was explained in more business words?

Comment: See among others [this Q&A](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/5586/37681) on the community position regarding Raspberry Pi's - despite that there are limited cases where you might use a Raspberry Pi in a production environment, they are considered hobby equipment and off-topic on server fault.

Comment: @HBruijn yes I see that but the question is still on-topic because technically the problem I have isn't related to the PI hardware. We had problem yesterday with the USB randomly disconnecting but that's not the Issue I was asking help for.

Comment: There removed any reference to the raspberrypi and replaced it by kiosk.

Answer (score 7):

On a fundamental level: We know that you are dealing with an RPi. Those are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and removing the reference to the actual device doesn't make this on-topic (in fact, this kind of editing usually makes the question a lot worse because you are omitting important information).

That said, even without the RPi in the picture, this is not a good practice for business networks (I don't say it's not necessary in your case) and you are a better off asking this on a site that deals more with this kind of cobbled together non-standard network, which would be superuser.com

Comment: Sadly it seems on server fault it's better to hide important information to get actual help. If I had a standard network I wouldn't be asking questions.

Comment: What is your problem? Why don't you try to ask the question at the place that can help you best?

Comment: Routing/Network issues not related to the hardware.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix You have it exactly backward: On SF it is important to _show_ important information. In particular the business context. This is a site about professional IT, not for generic computing questions. This happened precisely because you tried to hide important information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried to hide reference to the PI after it was marked as off topic for being a RaspberryPI question (which isn't), not the other way around.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the question didn't hide any information before it was put on hold, the edit I made weren't to hide anything but to move the focus out of the raspberry pi since the question got on hold for this while it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that RPi got a whole stackexchange site on is own. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

For advanced question about Linux in general, even RPi direct it to it, it's more on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

The close reason is maybe not the best as it don't point to those sites, but globally it's off-topic there.

Comment: Because the question is about networking in general and not about the raspberrypi. I'd have something else than a PI I'd be asking the same question.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I agree, but it's what OS in the PI ? it's related to that OS, which the expert are on the other site anyhow. As you guess it's only playing with your routing rule in the PI. The default route 0.0.0.0 should point to your laptop IP in the LAN that will bridge for the internet, and all other traffic will stay inside the LAN. or If you want to make those rule in the router, you need a router that can send ICMP redirect, thus that question will focus on the router now, not the kiosk anyway. The question should had been moved simply imo, as it's not bad, just not ontopic there

Comment: It's debian/Raspbian.